# How to get A1111 running with a fixed URL on AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, stable-diffusion

I am running A1111 on my AWS g4dn instance and it is working fine. However the issue happens when the app restarts and changes the URL. Then I need to SSH into the instance and take the new URL.

Can we either:

- Fix the URL where A1111 is running, so that it won't change even the app is restarting
- Redirect console logs to a log file, so that another app can read these files and extract out the URL.

It is a kinda pain to always login the instance and take the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to alloate an Elastic IP to your stable difussion instance, and then point a DNS name at that IP and configure that DNS name. EIPs currently cost $0.005/hour (~3.8 US$/month) but you would only need set the DNS name once. Each time the instance starts, regardless of the public hostname assigned it would be reachable by the preconfigured DNS name.

You also could do this without an EIP by creating a script that runs on instance startup that modifies the URL. From a script you can fetch the current hostname from `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname`